# css class selector not working and not sure why

Tags: jquery, css, selector

In my project you can click on a region and it's county crest appears at the bottom.

[my project](http://danu2.it.nuigalway.ie/09101916/qtipdemo2/)

I have some jquery to hover on the newly added crests and I want to use the selector on their class. Each crest is added with:

```
$("#selectResult").append("<div id='"+arr[this.id]+"' class='inline'></div>");
var addThis = arr[this.id];
$("#" + addThis).css({'background-image' : 'url(./coatofarms/'+arr[this.id]+'.png)',
'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
'background-position': 'bottom'});
```

and my jquery test hover is:

```
 $(".inline").hover(function(){
         alert('in');
}, function(){
         alert('out');
});
```

The class is .inline and yet the select does not work(?) Test on a div ID and it works perfectly. 
Could someone please tell me where I've gone wrong?
tia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you `.inline` append to DOM dynamically, so ordinary binding will not work here. You need delegate event handler to perform like following:

```
$('#selectResult').on('hover', '.inline', function(e) {
   if(e.type == "mouseenter") {
      alert('In');
   } else {
      alert('Out');
   }
});
```

[**`.on()`**](http://api.jquery.com/on) method for delegate event handler need to use as following:

```
$(container).on(eventName, target, handlerFunction);
```

Here, `container` points to the element that is Static-element i.e. belongs to DOM at page load, not append dynamically. Try to avoid `document` or `body` as `container` reference.

Comment: Thanks you very much. This one really had me scratching my head and it makes sense now. I also was using a very old version of jQuery which added to my troubles.

Answer (score 1):

If you're dynamically adding the element your going to need to set up a delegate in order to subscribe the given element to an event or events in this case.

Use jQuery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Something like:

```
$(document).on('mouseover mouseout', '.inline', function(e){
      if(e.type == 'mouseover')
      {
         alert('in');
      }
      else if(e.type == 'mouseout')
      {
          alert('out');
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(".inline").live("mouseenter",function(){
         alert('in');
}).live("mouseleave", function(){
         alert('out');
});
```

Comment: Hi mate, ,`live()` is deprecated, so don't use it. Try to  use `.on()` with jQuery >= 1.7